# How to use an UPDATE SQL statement with user input from Python?

Tags: python, mysql, input, sql-update

I'm new to Python and especially to SQL.

My goal is:

1. A user should enter which phone number he wants to change
2. Then the user should be able to enter the new phone number
3. This change should then be stored in my MySQL database

As I know the syntax for an update is like this:

```
sql = "UPDATE table SET fieldname = value" "WHERE fieldname = value"
```

But if I try to use the code with two variables from an input, it doesn't work:

```
input_change = input("Write the number to change: ")
input_new = input("Write the new number: ")
sql = "UPDATE table SET telefonnummer = ?" "WHERE telefonnummer = ?"
cursor.execute(sql, (input_change, input_new))
connection.commit()
```

Does somebody have an idea how I can fix this? Or where can I find a good description about using variables in SQL statements?

Many thanks for the answers.

Comment: What error code do you get?

Comment: Hello user148, could you try changing this `sql = "UPDATE table SET telefonnummer = ?" "WHERE telefonnummer = ?"` to `sql ='''UPDATE table SET telefonnummer = ? WHERE telefonnummer = ?'''`

Answer (score 1):

Change :

```
sql = "UPDATE table SET telefonnummer = ?" "WHERE telefonnummer = ?"
```

to

```
sql = "UPDATE table SET telefonnummer = ? WHERE telefonnummer = ?"
```

and

```
cursor.execute(sql, (input_change, input_new))
```

to

```
cursor.execute(sql, [input_change, input_new])
```

Comment: Cool! This sums it up, I got confused I thought the `input()` is only one. I think the code looks different in night mode :D

Comment: Hello Nir Elbaz & StackOffended
Many thanks for your answers.
Now I don't get an error anymore, but the update of the phone number does not happen in the database...

Comment: It works with this code you had written! :)) I had just to change the sequence here [input_new, input_change].

Thank you very much!

Comment: great! If I'm not mistaken making it a `tuple` or a `list` I think won't matter , either of the two I think would work as long as it provides the data correspondingly :)